# Download big remote files to client with PHP with resume capability

Tags: php, download

I think the title is explaining perfectly.

How I can deliver big REMOTE files to client with resume capability through PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely wouldn't want to use PHP for that, since it's not really made for this kind of task.

For Resume capability, your script needs to be able to read and act properly upon the [`Range:` HTTP request header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_Headers) the client sends, as well as correctly serve a `Content-length:` header at least.